# PostgreSQL timestamptz and timetz functions

Tags: postgresql, timezone-offset

I really need to store local date and time (aircraft wheels up date and time) and the utc offset so I can convert to utc to calculate intervals (flight duration). People travel on local time and you need utc for cross time zone computations. I had hoped to use timestamptz but it absolutely does *not* work for this purpose. It converts everything to a function of the postgres time zone. In my case this is `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mi:ss-07`.

However, I investigated timetz just to cover all the bases. It stores exactly what I need. It preserves the local time while providing the offset to utc. Except that now I need two columns instead of one to store the information.

My questions are:
Why do the timestamptz and the timetz functions give different results? 
Is there a way to make the timestamptz include the local time zone offset rather than the system time zone offset?
Here are the queries that illustrate the difference:

```
select cast('2015-05-01 11:25:00 america/caracas' as timestamptz)

-- 2015-05-01 08:55:00-07
;

select cast('2015-05-01 11:25:00 america/caracas' as timetz)

-- 11:25:00-04:30
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally find the wording `timestamp with time zone` confusing when trying to understand PostgreSQL's `timestamptz`, because it doesn't store any time zone. According to [the docs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Notice, on that page, that the storage characteristics and limits of `timestamp` and `timestamptz` are identical.

In my head, to keep things straight, I translate `timestamptz` to "timestamp in the real world", and plain `timestamp` to "you probably didn't mean to use this type" (because, so far, I've only found myself needing to store timestamps that *are* related to the real world.)

So:

> Why do the `timestamptz` and the `timetz` functions give different results?

It appears to be because PostgreSQL didn't feel they were allowed to make `timetz` work like `timestamptz` does:

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.

My guess is that some of these "properties" are the ones that they don't like, and you do.

And:

> Is there a way to make the `timestamptz` include the local time zone offset rather than the system time zone offset?

There's no offset being stored for `timestamptz` values. They're just real-world timestamps. So the way to store the local time zone is the way you've already thought of: store it separately.

```
create table my_table (
    happened timestamptz,
    local_time_zone varchar
);
select happened at time zone 'UTC', happened at time zone local_time_zone
    from my_table;
```

Comment: >> There's no offset being stored for timestamptz values. They're just real-world timestamps.

Actually there is an offset being stored; it is the offset of the postgres location setting. In my example it is -7 because my location happens to be in PDT. 
I remain baffled. Why do they bother? Why not just store it as UTC and be done with it? I see no value in knowing the offset of the setting for the postgres implementation if I want to know when a plane took off from Caracas.

Comment: My first quote from the docs that I linked to answers all that and more; read it again. They *do* just store it as UTC. When *converted to a string in the default way*, it shows it in PDT. That's not stored in it.

Comment: I'm confused. It is (was) 4:54 in Seattle, 7:54 in New York and 11:54 in London.

Comment: I'm confused. It is (was) 4:54 in Seattle, 7:54 in New York and 11:54 in London.
I run these commands:

create table timestamptz_tst (a timestamptz, b timetz);
insert into timestamptz_tst values('2015-05-02 07:54:00 america/new_york', '2015-05-02 07:54:00 america/new_york');
select * from timestamptz_tst;
-- 2015-05-02 04:54:00-07 07:54:00-04
Postgres converted new york time to west coast time and returned west coast time with the offset from utc. I wonder where the -7 comes from if postgres doesn't store it?

Comment: sorry, the timer got me

Comment: The `-7` comes from your computer's time zone being currently at `UTC-7`, or postgres being configured to use that time zone by default. It's not stored in the values.

Comment: Look at the example SQL code at the end of my answer. You can get the timestamp at any time zone you wish. You only get the default time zone when you convert to a string in the default way.

Comment: set time zone utc;
select *
from timestamptz_tst
-- 2015-05-02 11:54:00+00 07:54:00-04
;
Wow! you are correct. Sorry I was so slow. I truly do not understand the purpose of the timestamptz datatype. It is totally different from timetz.

Comment: It's for when you want to store timestamps. It takes care of time zone stuff for you rather than making you convert back and forth from UTC yourself. You can input in any timezone, and it will internally be converted to UTC, and then with the `at time zone` operator you can convert it to whatever time zone you want to see it in. It took me a while to understand it, too.